# Installing Haskell-gi on macOS Catalina and creating GUI in Haskell

Tags: macos, user-interface, haskell, gtk3

[Haskell-gi](https://github.com/haskell-gi/haskell-gi) seems to be the most up-to-date GTK to Haskell bindings library. Unfortunately, neither brew nor macports is able to install it properly, and their github offers no other alternatives for MacOS. I also tried to get it working on Windows and could not.

Does anyone have any information on the state of Haskell and GUIs in 2020? All the tutorials I've found are outdated, containing dead links or references to obsolete versions of things. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Some months ago I wrote a [small guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/efylna/haskell_gui/fc3xh18/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) on Reddit about Haskell GUI libraries, does that help at all?

Comment: A recent talk from Serokell about GTK GUI in Haskell had this very problem (haskell-gi on Mac) discussed: https://youtu.be/k1aq8ikO-8Q  (minutes 2–6). Their solution was to use Nix.